# How to apply CSS animation without refresh

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm implementing a paragraph using CSS animation and jQuery.

This CSS animation is applied when clicked, and then it returns the original text. When it is clicked the second time, the animation does not work. I have to refresh for it to update.

I want to implement this CSS's animation so that I don’t have to refresh after one click event.

Unnecessary code is abbreviated.
This is what I have so far :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#intro_bullet').click(function(){
     $('#intro span').addClass('animation');
  });
});
```

```css
.animation {
  animation-name: color_change;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: 2;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}


@-webkit-keyframes color_change {
  from { color: #333386; }
  to { color: white; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="intro_bullet">Intro</li>
</ul>

<div id="intro">
  <span>Paragraph about intro</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to remove the class first, and then there is a hack using `offsetWidth` that you can use to 'reset' the div so that the animation can run again.  [See here](https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/) for more information.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#intro_bullet').click(function(){
         $('#intro span').removeClass('animation');
         void $('#intro span')[0].offsetWidth;
         $('#intro span').addClass('animation');
    });
});
```

```css
.animation {
    animation-name: color_change;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-iteration-count: 2;
    animation-direction: alternate;
}


@keyframes color_change {
    from { color: yellow;}
    to { color: royalblue;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li id="intro_title">Intro</li>
    <li id="intro_bullet">Click here</li>
</ul>

<div id="intro">
    <span>Paragraph about intro</span>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much  for your answer. I've solved it thanks to you. I want to study more to you about 'offsetWidth'. What exactly does 'offsetWidth' mean? Anyway, Thank you very much :)

Comment: To be honest, I'm not exactly sure why the `offsetWidth` is necessary, but it is (see the link I posted).  `offsetWidth`'s primary purpose is used to get the width of an element in pixels.  My guess is that it is forcing some sort of re-draw of the DOM for that element.

Comment: i'm understand. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
```

Comment: thank you very much  for your answer. I'll take care of it.